# Retriving Sum of values under object collection using linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-6, iteration

I'm quite a rookie in linq. And wanted to solve this problem with linq so I can save some server trips.

Following is object structure.

```
EntityA{
    int Id,
    string Name,
    EntityB entityb
}

EntityB{
    int idb,
    string type,
    ICollection<EntityC> entityc
}

EntityC{
    int idc,
    ICollection<EntityD> entityd
}

EntityD{
    int idd,
    ICollection<EntityE> entitye
}

EntityE{
    int ide,
    int valuepoint
}
```

I need to retrieve particular (with some condition) EntityA with the SUM of valuepoint which is in EntityD. Currently I'm doing it through regular iterator. Retrieving collection from EntityB and storing in List and with help for foreach I'm able to resolve this. But in complex object and due to large database it's taking too much time to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
var results=db.EntitiesA.Sum(a=>a.EntitiesB.Sum(b=>b.EntitiesC.Sum(c=>c.EntitiesD.Sum(d=>d.ValuePoint))));
```

Another way:

```
var results=db.EntitiesA.Sum(a=>a.EntitiesB
 .SelectMany(b=>b.EntitiesC)
 .SelectMany(c=>c.EntitiesD)
 .Select(d=>d.ValuePoint));
```